# Hyper-V for dummies - what is the benefit?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-8-preview

As was announced, Windows 8 will have Hyper-V built in, and some people are much excited about that.

I can use Microsoft Virtual PC on Win 7 even now, how Hyper-V will make user experience better? Can anybody explain in simple terms?

Edit: I understand that Hyper-V is "closer to the metal" - but besides performance (BTW, what is the estimated performance gain?) is there any functionality that you gain by using Hyper-V? I can use network and USB from a Virtual PC...

Comment: Just like any feature, it's not useful if you'll never use it.  But the architectural changes that were necessary to get us here in the first place **is useful**.

Answer (score 3):

Virtual PC is a type 2 hypervisor, Hyper-V is a type 1 hypervisor the difference is illustrated here :

[image]

There are less layers which means better performances. Also, see Rory's answer.

**P.S**: Image was taken from [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hypervisor)

Answer (score 1):

This will only be of interest to you if you run virtual machines. For those that do, having a native hypervisor is very useful in terms of connectivity, enforcing separation of virtual machines, tear down and rebuild of VM's as these processes can be run at a lower level in the OS and effectively see their environment as much closer to the real world.